# Bash: how to count unique values in array and retrieve value with most duplicates

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bash script that pushes different width:height values onto the end of an array.  Some of the values are duplicates.  What I need to do is loop through the array, count the number of occurrences for each unique value in the array and then retrieve the value with the most duplicates.

```
dimensions=( )
dimensions[${#dimensions[*]}]="450:180"
dimensions[${#dimensions[*]}]="360:240"
dimensions[${#dimensions[*]}]="360:240"
dimensions[${#dimensions[*]}]="640:480"
dimensions[${#dimensions[*]}]="360:240"
dimensions[${#dimensions[*]}]="640:480"
```

In the array above I would need to retrieve the value "360:240" since there were 3 duplicates.  How can I count the unique values and end up with a variable containing the value with the most duplicates from the array?

```
mostDuplicates="360:240"
```

Comment: Can you use bash 4? If so, use an associative array and swap the keys and values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash version 4 has associative arrays:

```
#! /bin/bash
dimensions=(
    450:180
    360:240
    360:240
    640:480
    360:240
    640:480)

declare -A count
max=0

for d in ${dimensions[@]} ; do
    if (( ++count[$d] > max )) ; then
        max=${count[$d]}
        winner=$d
    fi
done
echo Winner: $winner, $max times
```